# Этика дублирования других ответов

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

*Возникла ситуация*: другой человек пересказал (мой) ответ. Да, это не ctrl+c/ctrl+v, однако общая структура и посыл ответа совпадает с точностью до кода, который в принципе к вопросу изначально не относился. Разница по времени между ответами была достаточной, чтобы увидеть изначальный ответ.

**Оригинальный ответ:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Второй по счету ответ, который лично я считаю дубликатом:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В наших ответах ровно 2 различия:

1. Информация про "несколько путей", *не вдаваясь в подробности, это неправда*
2. `speed` vs `Length`, *это в принципе не относится к вопросу, лично я добавил это в свой ответ просто так*

Прошу, не нужно идти ко мне в профиль или искать этот вопрос по метке, я ни в коем случае не хочу начать войну против конкретного человека. Я впервые попал в подобную ситуацию и не совсем понимаю, как на нее реагировать.

---

**Вопрос**: где начинается дубликат чужих ответов и начинается оригинальный материал? Нужны ли вообще ответы, которые полностью дублируют посыл и смысл других ответов?

**P.S.**

Вопрос не в том, чей ответ приняли и кто сколько получил плюсов, мне интересно мнение сообщества в вакууме.

Answer (score 9):

В ответе важны не только ключевые слова, но и понятность, широта (либо, напротив, точность), стиль в конце концов. В частности, приведённые вами два ответа я считаю совершенно разными. И нет никаких проблем в том, что одно и то же два разных участника попытались объяснить разными словами.

С правильной реакцией на эту ситуацию всё просто. Если чужой ответ набрал меньше рейтинга - можно ничего не делать. Если чужой ответ был дан позже и набрал больше рейтинга - значит, у вас есть пример для подражания :-)

Ещё некоторые участники иногда удаляют свой ответ, если видят что чужой ответ получился лучше. Но так делать необязательно.